# Interpretation of mean excess plots

Tags: generalized-linear-model, data-visualization, actuarial-science

[image]

I am trying to model claim severities for 2 types of insurance, and I want to determine if I should model large claims seperately or not. I am having a difficult time to interpret the mean excess plots. I get that for example, if mean excess increases liniarly with the threshold in the beginning, and the points are very spread afterwards, it can indicate something like a pareto distribution.

How do i interpret these mean excesses? They increase at some intervals, but overall they are decreasing? Does this mean that the large claims are not of concern, and I can model them in 1 singular model?

I tried to model the whole thing with a gamma and inverse gaus distributions, given my predictors. I looked at a raw residual plot, which looks relatively nice. [image]

The mean of the residuals lies in 0 almost everywhere, and the variance seems pretty constant. To me it looks nice, but I feel like I might be missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you calculating the **conditional** mean excess the threshold? That *should* be a non-decreasing function. See page 127 of McNeil (1997): https://www.casact.org/sites/default/files/database/astin_vol27no1_117.pdf